# Why does GitHub branch show lots of "joint" commits?

Tags: git

This often happens to me:

- Create branch `my-branch` locally with a few initial commits, add to a PR
- Push to GitHub
- Wait a few days for the branch to get reviewed
- Make and commit a few changes locally
- Run `git push origin my-branch`, and get the following error message:

> To github.com:myorg/myrepo.git  ! [rejected]          my-branch ->
>   my-branch (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to
>   'git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git' hint: Updates were rejected because
>   the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart.
>   Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before
>   pushing again.

- Run `git pull origin my-branch`, and get the following message (without errors):

> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...

- Run `git push origin my-branch`, this time without errors
- Look at the branch on GitHub, and see that it's now showing zillions of extra commits from master, which appear as "joint commits" by me and others in my team.

This is annoying, because it means the diff on the branch shows all the extra commits too, rather than just the changes I've made.

What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent this happening in future?

Probably one answer is for me to rebase before trying to push? But if so then the GitHub message is confusing, because it recommends `git pull`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely must use `git pull` but it could be "pull-with-merge" or "pull-with-rebase". Currently you do the former and you want the latter. The command is `git pull --rebase`.

To make "pull-with-rebase" the default configure it globally:

```
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
```

Reconfigure existing repositories and branches:

```
git config branch.$NAME.rebase true
```

For example:

```
git config branch.master.rebase true
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting is indicating that the remote branch has extra commits on it that your local doesn't. And since you have committed to your local as well, they are now out of sync.

The key point is that *someone* has committed on your remote branch. That's important not just for the conflict but for the integrity of your feature, so it's important to be aware of.

In your case however, it appears that in your most recent changes you've merged master into your branch. Then, you've effectively done a rebase of your branch on top of the remote branch. By default Git will flatten these commits, applying them directly to your branch instead of recreating the merge commit (see [--preserve-merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---preserve-merges)). This is why you can see all those commits now replayed in your branch as joint commits in Github.

If you didn't merge master into your feature branch, it may have happened on the remote branch, although it is more difficult to get into your end state if that's the case.

To avoid this situation:

1. Make sure to `git pull` before doing more local work.
2. Make sure to `git push` always after finishing your local work, especially if you know others are going to work on the branch.
3. Don't rebase merge commits (such as merges from master into your feature branch).